# Binary Classification: what if the class I care most is only small portion of the data?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

I'm working on a binary classification problem. Say class A and B.
But the problem is that the class prior distribution of A and B is like 90% and 10%. So most of the classification algorithms I've tried, they tend to classify most of the cases class A, though the 0/1 accuracy is high but the class precision and recall for class B is horrible. How can I change this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two basic approaches:

- Oversample the smaller class (duplicate vectors so the proportions are more equal, you can also apply some small noise to these data for more "valuable" data)
- Use some class-weighting scheme, which is supported by your model

In particular, heve a look at [the exact problem for Support Vector Machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18078084/how-should-i-teach-machine-learning-algorithm-using-data-with-big-disproportion/18088148#18088148)

And one more thing - some evaluation measures are constructed to deal with such disproportion, in partiular `MCC` (Mathews Correlation Coefficient) can be used to evaluate model quality on the non proportional data.

Answer (score 1):

[This research article](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=6029340) also defines some general class-weighting schemes which you can incorporate as the training criterion in your preferred learning algorithm.

In cost-based class weighting, you update the learning algorithm to handle the uneven classes in the training process using your data "as is", whereas sampling involves a data-level approach.

Some weighting schemes proposed in the above-mentioned article treat the accuracy of both classes as equally important, while others treat the minority class accuracy as more important than the majority class accuracy.